# Is my computer fast enough to play league of legends?

Tags: memory, performance, cpu, gaming

Do you guys think that a Intel Celeron E1200 Dual-Core Processor, with 2 gigabytes of ram is fast enough to play league of legends, provided that the rest of the system is good enough.

Comment: See System Requirements Labs' [Can You Run It?](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri).

Comment: @user2350459 - the reason that you have so many downvotes on this is because there is no evidence you tried to find this out for yourself by googling it, etc. If you ask future questions just put the steps you have taken or why that information isn't sufficient. Hope you'll come back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752654-Minimum-and-Recommended-System-Requirements#wq1

1GB of RAM and a 2GHz Processor is the listed specification. Your processor is only 1.6GHz but is a dual-core. Additionally, if you google that processor model there are posts on forums of people successfully playing league with it. So yes, you should be able to play but it may not be an optimal experience.

Comment: so 1.6 Ghz of dual core is better than 2Ghz?

Comment: @user2350459 "Better" is subjective. consider: [Quad cores have lower processor speed, are they still better?](http://superuser.com/questions/202376/quad-cores-have-lower-processor-speed-are-they-still-better), [CPU Cores: The more the better?](http://superuser.com/questions/2489/cpu-cores-the-more-the-better), etc.

Comment: There is a lot more that goes in to the calculation but, in this case, since others say it runs the game, it appears that your processor can keep up with the computations needed to run the game. 2 cores doesn't double the effective GHz, for the record, it's a much more complicated metric and MHz/GHz isn't always the best thing to go by. If you use the links listed above or do a search on "League of Legends 1.6GHz celeron" you will find that other people run the game successfully on that processor. :)

Comment: This is an acceptable answer to a question that shouldn't have been asked without prior research.

Comment: Sorry for that bad question, you guys are right, i  could've looked this up and found other users with the same build that have tried to play league on it. Thanks for all the input though. Should i delete this question?

Comment: You could do that or mark an answer for it, I'd do one or the other, always prefer not having them hanging without an answer and downvoted =(